# Can someone help me with this algebraic inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I found this inequality on twitter and I can't seem to prove the statement.

Prove that for $a,b,c > 0$ that

$$
\frac{a+b+c}{2} \geq \frac{ab}{a+b} + \frac{ac}{a+c} + \frac{bc}{b+c}
$$

After an hour (and a crick in my neck) I've only been able to turn it into

$$
a^3(b+c)+b^3(a+c)+c^3(a+b)-2abc(a+b+c) \geq 0
$$

and I'm not even sure if that's much better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\frac{bc}{b+c}+\frac{ca}{c+a}+\frac{ab}{a+b}<\frac{a+b+c}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026954/prove-that-fracbcbc-fraccaca-fracabab-fracabc2)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1745413/42969.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that by [HM-AM inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality)

$$\frac{ab}{a+b} + \frac{ac}{a+c} + \frac{bc}{b+c}=\frac{1}{\frac1a+\frac1b} + \frac{1}{\frac1a+\frac1c}+ \frac{1}{\frac1b+\frac1c} \le$$ $$\le\frac{a+b}4+\frac{a+c}4+\frac{b+c}4=\frac{a+b+c}2$$

Comment: Thank you so much, would you believe I was only reading about the inequalities with the various means yesterday but it never dawned on me to use it when I saw this.

Comment: @PatrickMcCarthy That's often the case with inequalities, you only need to become familiar solving a lot of them to guess the right way! You are welcome. Bye

Answer (score 1):

Since $(3,1,0)\succ(2,1,1),$ your inequality is true by Muirhead.